# Evaluate the double summation having an intimidating closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{20}\sum_{k=0}^{20-n}\frac{n}{n+k}$$

This series has taken much of my time and guess what, I'm not able to solve it as usual. I couldn't find any pattern or any telescopic here. So nonchalantly, I went on wolframalpha expecting a beautiful answer and possibly a beautiful closed form.

The answer was indeed pretty but there was no closed form. So I decided to just enter the later summation, the one with the summand $k$ and guess what, I discovered a closed form and that was $$\sum_{k=0}^{20-n}\frac{n}{n+k}=n\left(-\psi^{(0)}(n)-\gamma+\frac{55835135}{15519504}\right)$$ I don't even know what these variables mean.

The answer of the original summation is $115.$ Can anyone please tell how to evaluate it$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $115=\frac{20\times 23}{4}$.  What happens if you try the sum for small values of $n$ like $1,2,3$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As regards the wolfram's output, $\psi^{(0)}$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers). It is known that for any integer $n\geq 1$,
$$\psi^{(0)}(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$$
where $H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$ and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).
Therefore, for $1\leq n\leq 20$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{20-n}\frac{n}{n+k}=n\sum_{k=0}^{20-n}\frac{1}{n+k}=
n\sum_{j=n}^{20}\frac{1}{j}=n(H_{20}-H_{n-1})=
n\left(\frac{55835135}{15519504}-\psi^{(0)}(n)-\gamma\right)$$
where the numeric fraction is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_{20}$ ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B20%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D)).
So, as it is written, the inner sum HAS NOT a closed form.

On the other hand, the whole double sum HAS a nice closed form.

Hint. More generally, for $N\geq 1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-n}\frac{n}{n+k}
=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{j=n}^{N}\frac{n}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{1}{j}\sum_{n=1}^{j}n$$
where at the last step we swap the order of summation (it's a standard technique). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Damnnn....how are you people so pro..what can I do to become like you?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad This is a standard technique in evaluating double sums